# I'm not sure; but I guess the result was somewhat acceptable / acceptable (to some extent / to an extent)

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

Let's suppose the following scenario; do the sentences bellow mean the same?

> - How was the meeting Gary?
>
> a) I'm not sure; but I guess the result was somewhat acceptable.
>
> b) I'm not sure; but I guess the result was acceptable to some extent.
>
> c) I'm not sure; but I guess the result was acceptable to an extent.

Comment: In my opinion, **acceptable** is not a gradable adjective; something is either acceptable or it is not. If you were to change the adjective to something that is gradeable, for example **useful**, the three sentences would have the same meaning. Here is a link that discusses this: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/16150/to-a-degree-vs-to-an-extent

Comment: But **acceptable** is often used as a gradable adjective. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=somewhat+acceptable%2Cacceptable+to+a+degree%2Cacceptable+to+some+extent&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csomewhat%20acceptable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cacceptable%20to%20a%20degree%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cacceptable%20to%20some%20extent%3B%2Cc0

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=most+acceptable%2Cmore+acceptable%2Cleast+acceptable&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cmost%20acceptable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cmore%20acceptable%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cleast%20acceptable%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Note that many English-language grammar/style guides suggest semicolons should not be used with conjunctions. (e.g. "I'm not sure; I guess the result was somewhat acceptable" would be preferred.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three sentences have identical meanings.